# Estimote App: Beacon is not connected

Tags: iphone, ibeacon, estimote

I have three **Estimote beacons** and I connect them using the **Estimote** application. But **when I try to connect using another device, then it will show the lock icon.** I double check the credential through which I logged in Estimote app and they are same. So I am not able to identify what is the issue.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Here is the screenshots [image: Lock Image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you log in with the same Estimote account?
You need to log in with the same Estimote account then you can make setting on the Beacon.
Just click Devices => then on the top right corner you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yore Estimote account in One Device at a time. If you need to use another device you need to logout and login again in New device.